# Console output in Visual Studio 2010 C++ Like Chrome

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am A PHP Developer, and first time working in Visual Studio C++ and wondering if there is some way through which  i can display variables  or contents to debug my application.

Is there any functionality like Console in Chrome as `console.log(myvariable)`?

Comment: Run under debugger, add the variables you are interested in to Watch window. You don't need to sprinkle logging statements over your code - you can examine any variable at any time.

Comment: Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362.aspx You will have to format your "variables" however (maybe with the help of std::string)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the TRACE macro.

TRACE( "This is a TRACE statement\n" );